# Is there a way you can get chickens to lay eggs more often?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to start a chicken farm in minecraft pocket edition but my chickens aren't laying eggs very often, is there a way I can make them lay more often? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

More chickens. Or more patience, that works too. There isn't anything that makes them lay eggs more often.

At some point the [breeding](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Breeding) feature will be added to Pocket Edition – that will make chicken farms much more productive, since breeding chickens together increases their population much faster than waiting for them to lay eggs and then hoping it will spawn a baby chicken when thrown. But until the breeding feature is added, you simply have to wait, and patiently build up your chicken population. If you let your chicken population get large before slaughtering any, you'll eventually have so many that you'll be swimming in chicken eggs and can set up a separate food-chicken pen from your egg-laying pen, but it takes a while to get there.